# Select the first range of time values in order to add AM/PM

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe (df) in which df$time has time values like the following:

```
df$id   df$time
  1      12:20
  2      12:40
  3       1:00
  4       1:20
  5       2:00
  6       3:00
  7       3:15
  8       4:00
  9       7:00
 10      11:00
 11      12:00
 12      12:20
 13      12:40
 14       1:00
 15       1:30
 16       3:00
 17       4:00
 18       4:30
 19       5:00
 20       5:15
 21       8:00
 22      10:00
```

What I want is to indicate that the first range of time values (id 1:10), from 12:00 up to 11:59, is AM, and the second range, is pm.

to have sth like:

```
 df$id   df$time
      1      12:20am
      2      12:40am
....
.....
     11      12:00pm
     12      12:20pm
```

I have thousands of tables, I am thinking of a loop that will somehow put the first set, which will be df$time[i] < 12:00 OR df$time[i] < 1:00 and i < than a minimum number as am, but not sure if there is a more effective solution, something that will define that the first range of values is id 1:10 and the 2nd range is 11:22

Comment: You probably need to add an example of your desired output as an edit to your question, also what you've tried so far.

Comment: thank you, added more information

Comment: Is the ID the column that defines if an hour is AM or PM? So `ifelse(df$id %in% c(1:10),paste0(df$time,"AM"),paste0(df$time,"PM"))`?

Comment: Do all of your tables follow the pattern of the example you've provided?
For example: Will the first part of the table be AM and the second PM? Any chance you might have AM -> PM -> AM?

Comment: the sequence of values is the same to all the tables: I mean that the first range of values needs to have the AM attribute. But there are tables that may have 50 values, or other tables that may have 15 values. It is not that always the values with id 1:10 are am.

Comment: AntoniosK yes, the pattern is always the same. the first part is AM, the second part is always PM

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly quick.

```
df <- read.table(text="
id   time
  1      12:20
  2      12:40
  3       1:00
  4       1:20
  5       2:00
  6       3:00
  7       3:15
  8       4:00
  9       7:00
 10      11:00
 11      12:00
 12      12:20
 13      12:40
 14       1:00
 15       1:30
 16       3:00
 17       4:00
 18       4:30
 19       5:00
 20       5:15
 21       8:00
 22      10:00", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

hm2dh <- function(x) {
    hm <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, ":"))
    as.numeric(hm[,1]) + as.numeric(hm[,2])/60
}

ampm <- c("pm", "am")[(cumprod(sign(diff(c(0, hm2dh(df$time) %% 12))))+3)/2]

df$timep <- paste0(df$time, ampm)

df
#    id  time   timep
# 1   1 12:20 12:20am
# 2   2 12:40 12:40am
# 3   3  1:00  1:00am
# 4   4  1:20  1:20am
# 5   5  2:00  2:00am
# 6   6  3:00  3:00am
# 7   7  3:15  3:15am
# 8   8  4:00  4:00am
# 9   9  7:00  7:00am
# 10 10 11:00 11:00am
# 11 11 12:00 12:00pm
# 12 12 12:20 12:20pm
# 13 13 12:40 12:40pm
# 14 14  1:00  1:00pm
# 15 15  1:30  1:30pm
# 16 16  3:00  3:00pm
# 17 17  4:00  4:00pm
# 18 18  4:30  4:30pm
# 19 19  5:00  5:00pm
# 20 20  5:15  5:15pm
# 21 21  8:00  8:00pm
# 22 22 10:00 10:00pm
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` approach using the data you posted:

```
# example data
df <- read.table(text="
id   time
  1      12:20
  2      12:40
  3       1:00
  4       1:20
  5       2:00
  6       3:00
  7       3:15
  8       4:00
  9       7:00
 10      11:00
 11      12:00
 12      12:20
 13      12:40
 14       1:00
 15       1:30
 16       3:00
 17       4:00
 18       4:30
 19       5:00
 20       5:15
 21       8:00
 22      10:00", 
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

---

```
# create vectorised function to extract the hours
GetHrs = function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ":"))[1])
GetHrs = Vectorize(GetHrs)


df %>%
  mutate(hr = GetHrs(time),                                                        # get the hrs
         group = cumsum(hr == 12 & lag(hr, default = 0) != 12),                    # create 2 groups based on where 12 appears after a value from 1 to 11
         time_upd = ifelse(group == 1, paste0(time,"AM"), paste0(time,"PM"))) %>%  # update values based on the grouping
  select(id, time_upd)                                                             # keep only columns of interest

#    id time_upd
# 1   1  12:20AM
# 2   2  12:40AM
# 3   3   1:00AM
# 4   4   1:20AM
# 5   5   2:00AM
# 6   6   3:00AM
# 7   7   3:15AM
# 8   8   4:00AM
# 9   9   7:00AM
# 10 10  11:00AM
# 11 11  12:00PM
# 12 12  12:20PM
# 13 13  12:40PM
# 14 14   1:00PM
# 15 15   1:30PM
# 16 16   3:00PM
# 17 17   4:00PM
# 18 18   4:30PM
# 19 19   5:00PM
# 20 20   5:15PM
# 21 21   8:00PM
# 22 22  10:00PM
```

Answer (score 0):

We could convert the time values into modulo 1200 to find the cut point where `diff` is less than zero. The remainder could be done in a `Map`.

```
cp <- which(c(0, diff(as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df$time)) %% 1200)) < 0)
df$time <- unlist(Map(paste0, list(df$time[1:(cp-1)], df$time[cp:nrow(df)]), c("am", "pm")))
df
#    id    time
# 1   1 12:20am
# 2   2 12:40am
# 3   3  1:00am
# 4   4  1:20am
# 5   5  2:00am
# 6   6  3:00am
# 7   7  3:15am
# 8   8  4:00am
# 9   9  7:00am
# 10 10 11:00am
# 11 11 12:00pm
# 12 12 12:20pm
# 13 13 12:40pm
# 14 14  1:00pm
# 15 15  1:30pm
# 16 16  3:00pm
# 17 17  4:00pm
# 18 18  4:30pm
# 19 19  5:00pm
# 20 20  5:15pm
# 21 21  8:00pm
# 22 22 10:00pm
```

***Data***

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:22, time = c("12:20", "12:40", "1:00", 
"1:20", "2:00", "3:00", "3:15", "4:00", "7:00", "11:00", "12:00", 
"12:20", "12:40", "1:00", "1:30", "3:00", "4:00", "4:30", "5:00", 
"5:15", "8:00", "10:00")), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = "data.frame")
```